# How do I finish my account here?

Tags: support

How do I finish my account here? It doesn't meet my needs.
This is a support question.

Comment: what do you mean finish your account? you mean fill out you profile or something?

Comment: I mean to remove my account/profile completely.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to delete your account, you can follow the instructions [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/user-deletion).  This is an action that can not be reversed, so only use it if you're *sure* you don't want to keep your account.

Comment: I filled in as you instructed, and I hope to be removed as soon as possible.

Comment: @Ali we are sorry that you are going.